# Code Contracts in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I´m working with openjml for code contracts (openjml.org)

Is it possible to use it with Intellij?

I have been searching google, but can´t find anything about Code Contracts in Intellij

Regards

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no plugin that provides OpenJML support in IntelliJ IDEA. However, IntelliJ IDEA supports a limited form of code contracts through its own [@Contract annotation](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/annotations/src/org/jetbrains/annotations/Contract.java).